# How can use Freemarker to extract nodes from an XML document without including the namespace in the output?

Tags: xml, freemarker

I'm trying to use Freemarker as a combination of XSLT and templating.  In order to do this, I need to be able to extract the text of part of a DOM but not include the namespaces in the output.

My input XML is:

```
  <soap:update xmlns:soap="http://soap.borrower.random.com">
     <soap:cin>data</soap:cin>
     <soap:borrower>
        <soap:ID>data</soap:ID>
        <soap:SSN>data</soap:SSN>
        <soap:city>data</soap:city>
        <soap:first>data</soap:first>
        <soap:last>data</soap:last>
        <soap:line1>data</soap:line1>
        <soap:phone>data</soap:phone>
        <soap:state>data</soap:state>
        <soap:zip>data</soap:zip>
     </soap:borrower>
  </soap:update>
```

My template is:

```
    <#ftl ns_prefixes={"D":"http://soap.borrower.random.com"}>
    <#assign xmlmsg = message.contentAsXml>
    <update xmlns="http://mynewnamespace.org">
     <cin>555</cin>
     <borrower>
        ${xmlmsg.update.borrower.*.@@markup}
     </borrower>
    </update
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
    <update xmlns="http://mynewnamespace.org">
     <cin>555</cin>
     <borrower>
        <ID xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</ID>
        <SSN xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</SSN>
        <city xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</city>
        <first xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</first>
        <last xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</last>
        <line1 xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</line1>
        <phone xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</phone>
        <state xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</state>
        <zip xmlns="http://soap.borrower.random.com">data</zip>
     </borrower>
    </update>
```

Which is, of course, technically correct, but I really need to strip all the namespace declarations off the individual elements so that I can just stick that text into the  element I'm creating and have these elements assume the namespace of their parent.

Is there an easy way to do this?

TIA

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution here, it's not the prettiest thing, but it does work for this specific scenario.

Basically I can use the Freemarker `replace` built-in in regex mode to remove any occurrences of the xmlsns attribute, like this: `${xmlmsg.update.borrower.*.@@markup?replace('\\sxmlns=\"[^\"]*\"','','r'))}`.

It's a bit grim, and it won't work for all scenarios (e.g. when the namespace is specified with a prefix, but for my scenario it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can't... FreeMarker just generates text, and has no idea if the namespace was already declared in the output or not. So it stays on the safe side.

Personally, I wouldn't use FreeMarker for XSLT-like jobs where you transform XML to a similar XML. XSLT is just better on that, as it's specialized to output XML. FreeMarker XML support is more about extracting some data from XML, and print HTML based on it and such.